# Windows Batch to Exe Compiler

Tags: windows, gratis

I need a Software that compiles .bat files into .exe files.

It should:

- be free
- actually compile the batch file rather than just making a link and loading the batch file in the temp folder
- work on Windows 7 or 8

Comment: Do you care what licensing?

Comment: @NickWilde No, I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Bat To Exe](http://f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e) Converter:

- freeware
- can include additional files
- can include application icon
- portable

Here is a screenshot from http://f2ko.de

[image]

Comment: Looks nice, but unfortunatly isn't working on my Windows 8 PC. I'll test it on my Win7 PC as soon, as I'm at Home. Looks like it hasn't been updated since 2011...

Comment: Well, the .bat files are all working fine, as soon as i compile them and try to run them i get an Stopped working Error.

Comment: @user1 have you tried with administrator manifest?

Comment: Yes, same result. Even tried just a simple but (and .cmd) file with just "start" as content.

Comment: Try with a simple `bat` file with the contents `@echo "Hello World!"`. The program after `start` was a relative path? Did it have the `exe` extension?

Comment: Still get the same error. There was no programm after `start`, I called start itself, opening a new CMD-Window.

Comment: @user1 it seems it doesn't work on Windows 8. The last thing you may try is running in compatibility mode.

Comment: Even that doesn't work. Maybe it will work on my win7 PC. Thank you very much, anyways!

Comment: Worked fine on Windows 7

Comment: As of 2023, this is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [Advanced Bat to EXE Converter](http://www.battoexeconverter.com). It works fine for me though I don't like it's licensing (free and pro version and instead of feature restrictions it has a no redist clause in the free EULA). It also has a bunch of extra batch commands for enhanced batch file fun. You can include version information and icons (and external files as well).

- *be free:* Free version; EULA restriction on distribution of generated EXEs - PRO version for $40.
- *actually compile the batch file rather than just making a link and loading the batch file in the temp folder:* It is fully compiles and obfusticates pretty well too; you can't just open the exe with an archive program and extract the Batch file. You also can't get details by opening with notepad or something - at least easily even 7 letter words you can't find by search.
- *work on Windows 7 or 8:* I know it works on Windows 7 and the website states it works with Windows 8.

Comment: You can also use iexpress to convert bat to an exe. There is a lot of (probably deliberately made) misleading information about "Advanced Bat To Exe Converter." It works the same way like every other batch to exe conversion program. It does NOT 'compile' the batch file. The Batch is extracted to temp. I've made a test with Process Explorer: http://s7.postimg.org/3vj36zsob/advb.png

Answer (score 1):

I  think the best solution for you is [Batch Compiler](http://bc.gotek.info) It's more of an IDE.It has everything you need to develop a batch program.it compiles batch files genuinely.No packing or linking.It has Advance commands too.It also has a built-in debugger which checks your code for syntax errors.
If you are a batch lover, i think this is the perfect option for you.
[image]
Hope this helps.Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Bat-To-Exe on sourceforge compiles batch files to executables.
It is free, open source, portable, plain, very simple and works faultlessly.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bat-to-exe/

Answer (score 1):

JitBit's Bat-To-Exe is a batch file compiler as well.
Pretty much the same as Bat-To-Exe on sourceforge but Free for personal use only.

https://www.jitbit.com/bat-to-exe/

I hope this helps!

Comment: no longer exists. 404